# 3D Line Integral

Tags: integration, multilinear-algebra, line-integrals

I would realy appreciate your kind generous help with this one problem I'm working on in my Engineering Math Intro,

> Evaluate
>   $ \int_{c} xyz  $ ds
>   where C is the curve given by 
>   $ \vec r(t)=<t-2sint, t^2> $
>   and $ -3\le t \le 3 $

Seeing that the z function is zero in the provided parameterization, I couldn't help assuming the evaluation would go as follow:

$ \int_{-3}^{3} (t-2sint)(t^2)(0) \sqrt{(t-2sint)^2+(t^2)^2+(0)^2} dt$

which will bring 
$ \int_{-3}^{3} 0 dt =constant$

(I use the formula given in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI.aspx)

Am I making a mistake?

Comment: If you are in 3D, why vector $\vec r$ have only two components? If in 2D, $z$ is constant, may be

Comment: shouldn't your curve got to be in IR^2?

Comment: thank you for your concern. That confusion seems to be the problem faced by most of my classmates. Hmm if z is constant, would the answer be as stated above?